# How to output double quotes from an XSLT param?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with an application that needs to receive XML from my app with a node (going to call it `Expected`) that needs to contain double quotes as the value. Both are using version 1.0.
Example

```
<Expected>""</Expected>
```

What XSLT command would achieve this?

I have tried using a variable outside the stylesheet, assigning that variable literal double quotes or a concatenated string of the characters of ASCII 34  and passing that as a parameter.
Nothing seems to work.

```
<xsl:param name="twoQuotes"/>

<xsl:template match=/MyContainer/MyField">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<Expected><xsl:value-of select="$twoquotes"/></Expected>
```

Comment: How does it fail? What output do you get? The simplest XSLT instruction to produce this output is `<Expected>""</Expected>` [sic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="emptyString" select='""'/>
  <xsl:param name="twoQuotes" select="'&quot;&quot;'"/>
  <xsl:param name="default" select="'default'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <r>
      <Expected1><xsl:value-of select="$emptyString"/></Expected1>
      <Expected2><xsl:value-of select="$twoQuotes"/></Expected2>
      <Expected3>""</Expected3>
      <Expected4>&quot;&quot;</Expected4>
      <Expected5>"<xsl:value-of select="$default"/>"</Expected5>
    </r>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

given any input XML, produces this output XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
   <Expected1/>
   <Expected2>""</Expected2>
   <Expected3>""</Expected3>
   <Expected4>""</Expected4>
   <Expected5>"default"</Expected5>
</r>
```

showing various ways to output doubles quotes.

Note that `Expected1` shows no double quotes because the default value of `$emptyString` is actually an empty string, not a string containing two double quote characters.